# Edit the background color of both radio button & label section using html and css

Tags: html, css

I am trying to change the background color of both the radio button and label.
I want the "label" & "radio button" to become like the picture inserted below.

[image: out put image]

How I can choose and change them by CSS. Here is my HTML code.

```
<!-- ---question1--- -->
      <div class="quest">
        <h1>Question 1 of 10</h1>
        <h5>Question 1</h5>
        <div class="choice">
          
            <input type="radio" id="1" name="choose" value="o1">
            <label for="o1">Option 1</label><br>
            <input type="radio" id="2" name="choose" value="o2">
            <label for="o2">Option 2</label><br>
            <input type="radio" id="3" name="choose" value="o3">
            <label for="o3">Option 3</label><br>
            <input type="radio" id="4" name="choose" value="o4">
            <label for="o4">Option 4</label>

        </div>
      </div>
```

Thank all of you so much!

Comment: I updated the code according to your needs with custom radio button color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code as you want, So you can customize radio button color and label background color according to your needs.

```css
input[type="radio"] {
  cursor:pointer;
  accent-color: #a5a5a5;
}
.quiz-box {
  background: #dbdbdb;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.quiz-box .question-number {
  font-size: 18px;

  color: #222222;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  line-height: 25px;
}
.quiz-box .question-text {
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #000000;
  line-height: 28px;
  padding: 20px 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.quiz-box .option-container {
}

.quiz-box .option-container .option {
  background: #cccccc;
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 22px;
  color: #000000;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="quiz-box custom-box">
        <div class="question-number">
            Question 1 of 5
        </div>
        <div class="question-text">
            &nbsp;Color of sky ?
        </div>
        <div class="option-container">
           <div class="option"><input type="radio" id="1" name="choose" value="o1">
            <label class="o1" for="o1">Red</label></div> 
           <div class="option"><input type="radio" id="1" name="choose" value="o1">
            <label class="o1" for="o1">Black</label></div> 
           <div class="option"><input type="radio" id="1" name="choose" value="o1">
            <label class="o1" for="o1">Blue</label></div> 
           <div class="option"><input type="radio" id="1" name="choose" value="o1">
            <label class="o1" for="o1">Purple</label></div> 
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: @SoDa_Nguyen approve the answer if it is useful.

Answer (score 0):

Hope it will be helpful.

```css
.choice{
 background-color:pink;
 padding:20px;
margin-bottom:-12px;
}

.choice:hover{
 background-color:black;
 color:white;
 padding:20px;
margin-bottom:-12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="quest">
        <h1>Question 1 of 10</h1>
        <h5>Question 1</h5>
     
        
            <div class="choice choice-1"><input type="radio" id="1" name="choose" value="o1">
              <label class="o1" for="o1">Option 1</label></div><br>
             <div class="choice choice-2"><input type="radio" id="2" name="choose" value="o2">
               <label for="o2">Option 2</label></div><br>
             <div class="choice choice-3"><input type="radio" id="3" name="choose" value="o3">
               <label for="o3">Option 3</label></div><br>
             <div class="choice choice-4"><input type="radio" id="4" name="choose" value="o4">
               <label for="o4">Option 4</label></div>

      </div>
```